# Ractive component: how to get a reference for its DOM?

Tags: ractivejs

I have a Ractive component that includes within its template html a Bootstrap .collapse element. Calling show() and hide() on this will trigger Bootstrap show and hide transitions.

```
# the component template:
  <div id='my_component>
    <div class='collapse'>
        some stuff to show or hide in here
    </div>
  </div>


# the component code:

Ractive.extend({
  template : "#component_template",
  show : function(){
    // call show() on the .collapse element within the rendered template
    // but how to get a reference on that element?
  },
  hide : function(){
    // call hide() on the .collapse element within the rendered template
    // but how to get a reference on that element?
  }
})
```

How can I get a reference in the javascript to the collapse element? this.el seems to refer to the root (component's parent) and not the component's view fragment.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ractive.find(querySelector)`](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-find) is what you're looking for:

```
Ractive.extend({
  template : "#component_template",
  show : function(){
    this.find('.collapse').show();
  },
  hide : function(){
    this.find('.collapse').hide();
  }
})
```

Comment: +1, though of course it's a DOM node, not a jQuery selector, so if you wanted to use `.hide()` you'd need to wrap it like so... `$(this.find('.collapse')).hide()`. Or `this.find('.collapse').style.display = 'none'`.

Comment: yes it works. Thanks @martypdx and Rich Harris. I thought I'd tried that without success, but it's working now!